# Isomorphism of two groups on the same set via the knowledge of subgroups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

> Let $(H,∘)$ and $(H,∗)$ be two groups and $S⊆H$. Let $\langle S\rangle_{(H,\circ)}$ and $\langle S\rangle_{(H,\ast)}$ be the subgroups generated by $S$ in $(H,∘)$ and $(H,∗)$ respectively. If $\langle S\rangle_{(H,\circ)}=\langle S\rangle_{(H,\ast)}$ for all $S⊆H$, are they isomorphic?

I had some previous discussion regarding this question in the [Mathematics](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/mathematics) chatroom (the details can be seen [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/36/conversation/isomorphism)) but other than that I couldn't progress at all regarding this question.

The only observation (admittedly trivial) that I have been able to make is that the identity elements of the groups are identical. This follows by taking $S=\emptyset$.

Comment: You want to exclude trivial subgroups, right?

Comment: I think two nonisomorphic Tarski Monsters with the same prime $p$ gives a counterexample, because they are just disjoint unions of cyclic subgroups of order $p$, any two of which generated the whole group. But perhaps there are easier counterxamples!

Comment: I am not going to attempt to write down a proof right now, but I believe that the two groups of order $605$ referred to in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875767/) provide a finite counterexample.

Comment: It is true if both operations are abelian but that's kind of trivial.

Comment: @Marco: Sorry, but I don't understand the proof even in the case of such abelian operations.

Comment: In your linked answer, I don't understand how the condition $\langle S\rangle_{(H,\circ)}=\langle S\rangle_{(H,\ast)}$ for all $S\subseteq H$ is satisfied @DerekHolt.

Comment: @Marco I am guessing that you meant that it is true for finite abelian groups, or maybe finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: @DerekHolt, Yes I had a proof for the finite abelian case which I deleted after this comment by Tobias Kildetoft : "This seems to assume that the groups are finite, in which case the abelian case follows directly from the classification under the much weaker condition that the groups have the same number of elements of each order."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just for the record, here is the example that I mentioned in my comment. I am still not planning to write down a proof: I labouriosly checked that it works by computer.

As in my answer to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2875767/), we take
$$G = \langle x,y,z \mid x^{11}=y^{11}=z^5=1, xy=yx, x^z=x^4, y^z=y^5 \rangle,$$
$$H = \langle x,y,z \mid x^{11}=y^{11}=z^5=1, xy=yx, x^z=x^4, y^z=y^3 \rangle.$$
These are $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(605,5)$ and $\mathtt{SmallGroup}(606,6)$ in the small groups database.

Observe that we can write the elements of both $G$ and $H$ as
$$\{ x^iy^j : 0 \le i \le 10,\,0 \le j \le 10\} \cup
\{ x^i(y^j z)^k: 0 \le i \le 10,\,0 \le j \le 10,\, 1 \le k \le 4 \}, $$
and we use this representation to identify the elements of the underlying sets of $G$ and $H$. We do it this way to make the subgroups of order $5$ correspond in the two groups.

The subgroups of order $11$  are all contained in the normal subgroup $\langle x,y \rangle$ and obviously correspond. So it really only remains to check that the $22$ subgroups of order $55$ correspond. Note that half of these contain $\langle x \rangle$ and the other half contain $\langle y \rangle$. I convinced myself that they did correspond and then checked it by computer.

*Added*: I think that insisting that the two groups should have the same underlying sets is confusing. Here is an equivalent statement of the problem, which I find easier to work with.

Do there exist non-isomorphic group $G$ and $H$ such that there is a bijection $\phi:G \to H$ that induces a bijection between the subgroups of $G$ and the subgroups of $H$. That was the version that I verified by computer.

Comment: You wrote, "we use this representation to identify the elements of the underlying sets of $G$ and $H$". But there is exactly one underlying set $H$ and when I say that $\langle S\rangle_{(H,\circ)}=\langle S\rangle_{(H,\ast)}$, I don't mean that they are **isomorphic**. I meant that they are **identical**.

Comment: Once you have identified two objects then they are identical.

Comment: Can you please tell me what is the definition of identification of two elements that you are using?

Comment: I just mean that the displayed set in my answer can be taken to be the underlying set of both $G$ and $H$. Just ignore the part about identifying the elements if you find that confusing.

Comment: I don't understand how your version of the OP, "Do there exist non-isomorphic group $G$ and $H$ such that there is a bijection $ϕ:G→H$ that induces a bijection between the subgroups of $G$ and the subgroups of $H$." is **equivalent** to the OP itself. In OP, the bijection $\phi$ should be the identity map and the induced bijection also should be the identity map between the sets of subgroups of the respective groups.

Comment: I am sorry that you don not understand it. Given $\phi$ as in my condition, we can define the second operation $\circ$ on $H$ by $h_1 \circ h_2 = \phi(\phi^{-1}(h_1)\phi^{-1}(h_2))$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience in clearing my doubts. I think I got it now.